# How to manually plot users current location on Google Maps from Android and getting the center and Radius

Tags: android, api, google-maps, location, maps

Using `Android Studio 2.0`, and `Google Maps API`, how can I plot users' current location in the map?

However, along with that, I also want to store the center and radius of the location circle plotted.

I searched over the web but did not find any method to plot the location in a way which returns the `Latitude` and `Longitude` and the `Radius` of the location plotted in the map(atleast not in Android) , but rather found methods which directly plot the location without returning any values.

So how to I plot the location and **get those values**?

IN A NUTSHELL,

I am looking to retrive the `centre` and `radius` of the circle plotted by `setMyLocationEnabled(true)` preferentially(but not necessarily) without plotting it.

Comment: Have you tried using 'Location Data'? it is use to get the current position of the device. Typically, most geolocation services use network routing address or internal GPS devices to determine this location. https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/location

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with [FusedLocationProviderApi](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/FusedLocationProviderApi)?

It has a method [GetLastLocation](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/FusedLocationProviderApi#getLastLocation%28com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient%29) that returns a [Location](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/location/Location.html). And with this Location you can get the accuracy (radius) and the latitude and longitude.

EDIT:
Some code from the [Developers page](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/training/location/retrieve-current.html) (sorry, I haven't got too much experience with location in Android)

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements
    ConnectionCallbacks, OnConnectionFailedListener {
...
@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
    mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(
            mGoogleApiClient);
    if (mLastLocation != null) {
        mLatitudeText.setText(String.valueOf(mLastLocation.getLatitude()));
        mLongitudeText.setText(String.valueOf(mLastLocation.getLongitude()));
    }
}
}
```

Comment: I checked it out, but the problem is that it can return null even if GPS and mobile networks are available. 'setMyLocationEnabled(true)' never fails afaik.